# Luxe giving errors when building to windows target

Tags: game-engine, haxe, hxcpp, luxe

I have been trying to build luxe with flow to windows target, and it has been giving me errors. I have tried building with '--arch 64' and '--arch 32' and it gives the same result.

I have also installed hxcpp (just putting that out there so that you know), OpenAL, and Visual C++ as the setup guide has instructed.

Everything is up to date.

Web builds work perfectly fine.

Here is the error log:

```
Error: While running :cl.exe -Iinclude -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//lib/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//lib//ogg/include/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//lib//vorbis/include/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//lib//theora/include/ -DNATIVE_TOOLKIT_OGG -DNATIVE_TOOLKIT_VORBIS -DNATIVE_TOOLKIT_THEORA -DLINC_OPENAL -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_openal/git//linc/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_opengl/git//linc/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_opengl/git//lib/glew/include/ -DLINC_OPENGL_GLEW -DGLEW_STATIC -DLINC_SDL -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_sdl/git//linc/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_sdl/git//lib/sdl/include/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_sdl/git//lib/sdl/include/configs/windows/ -DHAVE_LIBC -DNATIVE_TOOLKIT_SDL -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_stb/git//lib/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_stb/git//linc/ -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_timestamp/git//linc/ -nologo /WX- /fp:precise -DHX_WINDOWS -GR -O2 -FS -Oy- -c -EHs -GS- -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hxcpp/3,3,49/include -DHXCPP_M64 -DHXCPP_VISIT_ALLOCS -DHXCPP_API_LEVEL=321 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_ALLOW_MSC_VER_MISMATCH -D_ALLOW_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL_MISMATCH -wd4996 -MT -Yuhxcpp.h /FpC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/luxe/git/samples/empty/bin/windows64.build/cpp/obj/msvc1964-nc/__pch/haxe/hxcpp.pch C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp -FoC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/luxe/git/samples/empty/bin/windows64.build/cpp/obj/msvc1964-nc/39abceb4_linc_ogg.obj
linc_ogg.cpp
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(9): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'newOggVorbisFile'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(9): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(9): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(15): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'vf'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(15): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(39): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'vf'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(39): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(39): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(50): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'OggFile'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(52): error C2065: 'ov_callbacks': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(52): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'cb'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(52): error C2065: 'cb': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(52): error C3861: 'ov_callbacks': identifier not found
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(54): error C2065: 'cb': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(54): error C2228: left of '.read_func' must have class/struct/union
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(54): note: type is 'unknown-type'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(54): error C2065: 'ogg_read_func': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(55): error C2065: 'cb': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(55): error C2228: left of '.seek_func' must have class/struct/union
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(55): note: type is 'unknown-type'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(55): error C2065: 'ogg_seek_func': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(56): error C2065: 'cb': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(56): error C2228: left of '.close_func' must have class/struct/union
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(56): note: type is 'unknown-type'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(56): error C2065: 'ogg_close_func': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(57): error C2065: 'cb': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(57): error C2228: left of '.tell_func' must have class/struct/union
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(57): note: type is 'unknown-type'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(57): error C2065: 'ogg_tell_func': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(62): error C2065: 'initial': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(63): error C2065: 'vf': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(63): error C2228: left of '.get_raw' must have class/struct/union
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(63): note: type is 'unknown-type'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(63): error C2065: 'cb': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(63): error C3861: 'ov_open_callbacks': identifier not found
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(65): error C2065: 'vf': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(65): error C2228: left of '.get_raw' must have class/struct/union
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(65): note: type is 'unknown-type'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(65): error C2065: 'initial': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(65): error C2065: 'ibytes': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(65): error C2065: 'cb': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(65): error C3861: 'ov_open_callbacks': identifier not found
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(72): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(72): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'read_fn'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(73): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(73): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'seek_fn'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(74): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(74): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'close_fn'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(75): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(75): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'tell_fn'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(79): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_read_fn'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(83): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(83): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(107): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 4 arguments
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(121): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'ogg_int64_t'
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(127): error C2065: 'offset': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(127): error C2065: 'whence': undeclared identifier
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(137): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/linc_ogg/git//linc/linc_ogg.cpp(147): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

flow /
 build - stopping because of errors in hxcpp compile, while building arch 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that you have the correct hxcpp lib version for Luxe. I have seen this error before when I ran:

`haxelib install hxcpp`

but in the guide it states to explicitly use version **3.2.205**

`haxelib install hxcpp 3.2.205`

You may need to first remove the older version by deleting the `hxcpp` folder in `C:\HaxeToolkit\lib` (or wherever your path is).